# General topology, compact sets, neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

[I'm really struggling in writing the proof of these statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSJSN.png)

My answers are:
1)true
2)true
3)false
but i can't supply the proof for this. Any help please? I don't know how to write proofs. I'm new to this course

Comment: You must provide further context concerning the topological space that is involved. If there is none then think of indiscrete topology for counterexamples.

Comment: This is how the question is asked. But we've been recently working with metric spaces if that's helpful

Answer (score 0):

By metric spaces your answers are correct.

1) If $p\neq q$ then $d(p,q)>0$ and for $\epsilon=\frac12d(p,q)>0$ the sets $U_p=\{x\in X\mid d(p,x)<\epsilon\}$ and $U_q=\{x\in X\mid d(q,x)<\epsilon\}$ are disjoint open sets containing $p$ and $q$ respectively.

2) Similarly for $i=1,\dots,k$ let $U_i$ denote an open set containing $p_i$ and let $V_i$ denote an open set containing $q$ with $U_i\cap V_i=\varnothing$. Now take the union of the $\bigcup_{i=1}^nU_i$ and $V=\bigcap_{i=1}^n V_i$.

3)Counterexample: $\mathbb R$ with usual topology with $p_i=\frac1{i}$ and $q=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I didn't understand your answer in part 2) can you explain furthermore?

Comment: In my answer on 2) there was a mistake (repaired now). Sorry for causing confusion.

Comment: What happens then in 2) if we take the union of the ⋃ni=1Ui and V=⋂ni=1Vi

Comment: Both are open, and they are disjoint. The union contains the $p_i $ and the intersection contains  $q $.